# Why this mySQL LEFT JOIN won't work? Can it be the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I'm making a PHP script to show to which user roles the current user belongs.
The data is in mySQL and what I want is to show all available roles and of all of them, show where the user belongs to.

**this is my roles table**

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
    roleID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
)
```

The roles here are:

```
registered
pending
student
former-student
```

**and this is the table that connects the usuarios table with the roles table**

```
CREATE TABLE rolesUsuarios (
    rolesUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
)
```

**I'm trying to create a LEFT JOIN like this:**

```
SELECT  
roles.nombreRol,
rolesUsuarios.userID
FROM roles 
LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
WHERE rolesUsuarios.userID = 183
```

(I'm not concerned with security at the moment, just checking that the query is working)

In the example, the user 183 has the roles *registered* and *student*.

**The intended result should be like this:**

```
nombreRol -------- userID
registered ------- 183
pending ---------- NULL
student ---------- 183
former-student --- NULL
```

But I get this result instead:

```
nombreRol -------- userID
registered ------- 183
student ---------- 183
```

How may I change the join? (I've followed the example [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) and it does work there, and I think that I've followed the logic of the query correctly)

Comment: ` OR.... IS NULL`

Comment: @PM77-1 - Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`. Add it to the `ON` clause of the join instead.

Try this:

```
SELECT  
roles.nombreRol,
rolesUsuarios.userID
FROM roles 
LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
AND rolesUsuarios.userID = 183
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work! Why the where clause does that to the query? Thank you!!

Comment: @Rosamunda -  because the `where` clause is applied after the join. If there was no matching values in the right table for a row in the left table,  the value of rightTable.userId will be null. So, when comparing a null with 183, it will evaluate to false and thus the row get excluded from the result. The `ON` clause is evaluated while the tables are being joined. So, it works correctly there.

Answer (score 0):

I thinhk the result is correct. If you want to get your expected result, your WHERE condition should like that:
WHERE rolesUsuarios.userID = 183 or rolesUsuarios.userID is NULL